# Checking a byte inside of a loop doesn't work

Tags: rust

I'm building a translator that should convert words into Pig Latin (i.e. the word *apple* to *apple-hay* or word *happy* to *appy-fay*). If the word begins with vowel, it doesn't drop it and adds `"-hay"` to its end, and drops the first letter if it is consonant and adds `"-fay"` to the end:

```
use std::str;

fn main() {
    // The case when it works perfectly well
    let dict = String::from("Hello").into_bytes();

    let vowels: Vec<u8> = vec![b'a', b'e', b'i', b'o', b'u'];

    let mut result = String::new();

    for c in vowels.iter() {
        if &dict[0] == c {
            result = str::from_utf8(&dict).unwrap().to_owned() + "-hay ";
        } else {
            result = str::from_utf8(&dict[1..]).unwrap().to_owned() + "-fay";
        }
    }
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

The code compiles without any errors or warnings and if I pass a string that begins with consonant it works perfectly well. However, when I pass a string that starts with a vowel, e.g. *apple*, the function behaves just like it began from a consonant and still performs actions from the `else` block. What is my error here?

Comment: Your description doesn't match [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break once you find a matching vowel... Otherwise, unless the first letter of the string happens to be the last vowel in your set, once you match it, you'll

- continue to compare the first letter of the string against every other vowel,
- find that it doesn't match, because obviously a letter can't be two or more vowels at once, and hence
- conclude - potentially multiple times, and finally - that the first letter of the string is a consonant.

Anyway, that should be a separate function, not `main()`, and just `return` once you find a match, so you won't need a `result` variable or `break`.

Comment: Thank you, that was too obvious and I completely missed it!